# What is wrong with this XML, not well formed?

Tags: xml

I have this XML now (created from a PHP array):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<documentation_export>
<_data_documentation>
    <309>The quick brown fox jumps over prepared statement.</309>
    <310>Test 1</310>
    <312>Test 2</312>
    <313>nmnmnmnmn</313>
</_data_documentation>
</documentation_export>
```

It shows XML Parsing Error: not well-formed..I'm not very familiar with XML format.
Is this XML file still usable or can be converted back to a PHP array variable (despite having the error)?

Thanks for any help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Structure-wise it looks fine, but I don't think tags can be named with or start with numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Tag names must not start with number, string `xml` or punctuation character. Read more http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp

Comment: Underscores are allowed. Just no digits (and not the string `xml`).

Comment: Actually the string "xml" is allowed as an element name; it's merely discouraged and reserved for future use. Parsers will allow you to use it, but you're running a risk that the rules may change in the future.

Comment: Also, http://w3fools.com is not a reliable source of information. The page you linked to contains incorrect information, too (it forgets about `=` which is illegal in xml tag names, for example).

Answer (score 0):

I think error is occurring when you are generating the xml . 
Just validated this xml using w3 validator . Total 7 error found one is :

***Line 4, Column 5: character "<" is the first character of a delimiter but occurred as data
    <309>The quick brown fox jumps over prepared statement.
✉
This message may appear in several cases:
You tried to include the "<" character in your page: you should escape it as "<"
You used an unescaped ampersand "&": this may be valid in some contexts, but it is recommended to use "&", which is always safe.
Another possibility is that you forgot to close quotes in a previous tag.***

Hear is the link of [w3validator](http://validator.w3.org/)

So i think solution reside in the code where XML is generating .